# Java argument type mismatch while reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to run some method I load from another jar, that returns an integer, and then I want to return it to another class and pass it to my logic.

I made my method loading class pretty simple like this:

```
public class ModuleLoader {

    private Class<?> cls;

    public void initializeCommandModule(Module m) throws Exception {
        URL url = this.getURL(m.getJar());
        this.cls = this.loadClass(m.getMainClass(), url);
    }

    public int execute(Module m, ArrayList<String> args) throws Exception {
        Method method = this.cls.getDeclaredMethod("execute", ArrayList.class);
        return (int) method.invoke(this.cls.newInstance(), 1);
    }

    public int respond(ArrayList<String> args) throws Exception {
        Method method = this.cls.getDeclaredMethod("response", ArrayList.class);
        return (int) method.invoke(this.cls.newInstance(), 1);
    }

    private Class<?> loadClass(String cls, URL url) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{url});
        Class<?> toReturn = loader.loadClass(cls);
        loader.close();

        return toReturn;
    }

    private URL getURL(String jar) throws MalformedURLException {
        return new File(jar).toURI().toURL();
    }

}
```

Take a look at the `execute(Module m, ArrayList<String> args)` method, this line throws the error:

```
    return (int) method.invoke(this.cls.newInstance());
```

The jar library I load looks like this:

```
public class Test {

    public int execute(ArrayList<String> i) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Why when I run that method I get the following exception thrown?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at ben.console.modules.ModuleLoader.execute(ModuleLoader.java:24)
    at ben.console.CommandProcessor.process(CommandProcessor.java:37)
    at ben.console.Console.listen(Console.java:25)
    at ben.console.Console.main(Console.java:31)
```

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to pass an argument to your method invocation.

```
return (int) method.invoke(this.cls.newInstance(), myArrayList);
```

You can also invoke with a null argument:

```
return (int) method.invoke(this.cls.newInstance(), (Object[])null);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `execute()` method, you have this

```
return (int) method.invoke(this.cls.newInstance());
```

I think you wanted

```
return (int) method.invoke(this, args);
```

Likewise with `respond()`,

```
Method method = this.cls.getDeclaredMethod("response", ArrayList.class);
return (int) method.invoke(this.cls.newInstance(), 1);
```

should be

```
return (int) method.invoke(this, args);
```

You may find my [blog post here](http://www.frischcode.com/2013/11/reflections.html) helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you fetch method that accepts one argument of type `ArrayList`:

```
Method method = this.cls.getDeclaredMethod("execute", ArrayList.class);
```

But then try to invoke it with argument of type that I cannot recognize that is obviously not `ArrayList`

```
(int) method.invoke(this.cls.newInstance());
```

What is the type of `this.cls.newInstance()`?  Value of `cls` is assigned in method `initializeCommandModule()` as following:

this.cls = this.loadClass(m.getMainClass(), url);

where `m` is `Module`. I have no idea what `Module` is and therefore do not know what does `getMainClass()` return.

Answer (score 1):

this error can happen if you load the class of the method and the class of a parameter with different `ClassLoader`

Answer (score -1):

You can also try to convert it into integer. I am having the same issue and I have been pulling off my hair. Using Integer.parseInt it did the trick. I hope this will help.

Here is a sample code:

```
String num = "1";
int result = Integer.parseInt(num);         
System.out.println(result);
```